# Css not loading in frontend in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, js-css

In Local , all css and js files have the url start form https:// but i want http://. where to change it .

Thanks.

Comment: change base url protocol in core_config_data

Comment: I already done it ... but nothing to change it.

Comment: run indexer and redeploy static view files

Comment: I have run all commands ...but not working

Comment: even deleting cache folders

Comment: yes ...........